# ASM uses registers yet the CPU still has sufficient?

Tags: assembly, x86, operating-system, cpu-registers, context-switch

I have watched some tutorials on ASM programming and I am at the very beginner stage. I am interested in learning x86 ASM, having a background in C, and I did some beginner MIPS during a Computer Science course which required me to write very basic programs. I was using registers like variables, without really understanding them.

I do not understand how registers in ASM are so freely used, when I believe a CPU might only have eight general purpose registers, and even less for specific purposes.

Surely, the fact that there are numerous different programs running at the same time on a modern Windows/Linux/OSX system, the registers would quickly be occupied by other programs? Especially if numerous ASM coded programs are running, where each one wants to use the CPU's registers for different purposes...

Also, is there a limit to how many registers I can use in x86 ASM? What happens if I need more, for example in C I could create an almost infinite amount of variables.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> Windows/Linux/OSX system, the registers would quickly be occupied by other programs?

When an OS switches from one program to another (on the same CPU); it stores the values that the previous program had in registers (in RAM) and then loads the next program's values into registers (from RAM).

> Also, is there a limit to how many registers I can use in x86 ASM? What happens if I need more, for example in C I could create an almost infinite amount of variables.

Yes, there's a limit (e.g. 32-bit 80x86 is limited to 7 general purpose registers, and 64-bit 80x86 is limited to 15 of them). If you create more variables then some variables just use space on the stack instead; and the compiler can move variables between the stack and registers whenever it feels like.

Comment: Out of curiosity, is there a way to forbid the computer from putting a register into RAM? There is security software like TRESOR and RAM-Crypt which provide security against coldboot attacks by not storing the keys in RAM, but instead within a CPU register.

Comment: I thought if I created variables on the stack, then I could not be able to change the data at runtime to another value?

Comment: @questioner: There's general purpose registers and often there's special purpose registers for all kinds of things. Some special purpose registers may be restricted in various ways (potentially including not being able to store them to RAM); but this all depends on what the CPU manufacturer felt like providing (software can only decide how to use what the CPU manufacturer provided).

Comment: @questioner: The stack is just normal RAM, and its easy for software to modify anything on the stack.

Comment: Ohhh, I thought it was like C where the stack stores static variables that cannot be changed, whereas the heap stores dynamically allocated memory at runtime which you can also change. Hopefully I am not getting confused.

Comment: @questioner: The number of static variables can change in C (e.g. you can do something like `if( something ) { int new_static_variable = 4; new_static_variable++; }` and the `new_static_variable ` will be created and auto-destroyed at the end of the scope/at the `}`); and the contents of static variables can be changed (e.g. `foo++` modifies the value in the static variable called `foo`) unless you deliberately prevent it (e.g. with `const`).

Comment: @questioner: In C, static storage class (used by global and `static` variables) is neither stack nor "heap".  In asm, it's space in `section .data` or `section .rodata`.  What Brendan mentioned in his last comment are *automatic* storage class, i.e. the default for local vars inside a function.  Those do go on the stack.  (BTW, this is what the `auto` keyword means in C, and C++ before C++11 redefined it as inferring types.)

Comment: Sometimes, something like `movq xmm0, rsp` could be useful to use `rsp` freely. Yes there was a leaf function where I needed exactly 16 temporary values. If I needed just one more, then I would've had to use the stack and `rsp` anyway.

Comment: Out of curiosity, is there a way to forbid the computer from putting a register into RAM? There is security software like TRESOR and RAM-Crypt which provide security against coldboot attacks by not storing the keys in RAM, but instead within a CPU register.

Comment: @questioner: Literally, no. For some cases (hardware virtualization, when the CPU is turned off for power management) all registers must be saved somewhere (in RAM, and then maybe on disk) or the contents would be lost forever. "Less literally", an OS can use special purpose registers for special purposes (and never save them to RAM itself). In theory it'd be possible for an OS (plus compiler, etc) to treat one or more general purpose registers as a special purpose register and not save it/them to RAM too, but it'd be a security problem (hard to prevent a malicious program from altering).

Comment: @questioner: Note that modern 80x86 has 15 general purpose registers, and instruction pointer and stack pointer; plus 16 FPU/SIMD registers (for FPU, MMX, SSE, AVX); plus 5 control registers; plus 6 debug registers; plus a model specific number (maybe a few hundred) of MSRs (Model Specific Registers). Out of "maybe about 250 registers" an OS might only save and load 34 of them during task switches.

Comment: So which one do I use if I want something to never end up in RAM or swapped to disk? Malicious programs and crashes are out of scope.

Comment: @questioner: Normal software (excluding "kernel") typically doesn't have permission to use most registers (can't use control registers, MSRs, etc) and is only able to use registers that the OS can/will save to RAM during task switches. With this in mind; it'd be easier to convince the OS to not do any task switches temporarily (while confidential data is in registers); but that would also be a security problem (if software can ask OS to not do task switches for security reasons, then malicious software can ask OS to not do task switches for "denial of service" reasons).

Comment: @questioner: I would expect that the security software you're thinking of is literally doing nothing at all to prevent the OS from saving confidential data from its registers into RAM; and instead is relying on "low probability" - like "There's 1 chance in 10 million that a task switch will occur and the data will be saved in RAM; and this is close enough to pretend that the confidential data won't ever be saved in RAM".

Comment: @questioner: Also note that it may not be just task switches; and IRQ handlers may also save the interrupted code's register contents to their stack (and restore the interrupted code's register contents after handling the IRQ before returning to the interrupted code). In this case; some kernels "strongly discourage" (which isn't a strict guarantee) the use of SIMD registers (to avoid the performance cost of saving/loading it); so SIMD registers might be preferred for confidential data.